# Correct way to override what() from std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, overriding

I have the following custom exception:

```cpp
#ifndef BLATT4_OUTSIDESEABOUNDS_H
#define BLATT4_OUTSIDESEABOUNDS_H

#include <exception>

namespace GameObjects {
    class OutsideSeaBounds : public std::exception {
    public:
        [[nodiscard]] const char * what() const noexcept override;
    };
}

#endif
```

```cpp
#include "OutsideSeaBounds.h"

namespace GameObjects {
    const char *OutsideSeaBounds::what() const noexcept
    {
        return "Das Schiff muss im Wasser liegen";
    }
}
```

However, my IDE, CLion, gives me a warning *Function 'what' hides a non-virtual function from class 'exception'*.
Why is that and how do I *override*, not *hide* the function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, your IDE is being silly.

A style note: `[[nodiscard]]` seems quite out of place here, even if not technically wrong it is not going to help anyone.